# Making a function that changes a variable every 3rd second

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout, var

I'm making a small game, and i want to make some dots that changes their x-position every 3rd second. My broblem is that it only prints out the first value. 
Im trying to make it as simple as possible.

I tried console.log(i), and figured that the loop worked fine, but the randomX var doesnt change more than once.

```js
var randomX = 0;
var i = 0, spawnXCount = 10;

function makeRandomXPosition(){

 i++;
 if (i < spawnXCount){
  setTimeout(makeRandomXPosition, 3000);
  
 }
 randomX = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)+1;
}


makeRandomXPosition();
console.log(randomX);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have works. It just looks like it's only doing it once simply because of where you put your `console.log()`. Move it into the function and you'll see it is changing each time.

```js
var randomX = 0;
var i = 0, spawnXCount = 10;

function makeRandomXPosition(){
    i++;
    if (i < spawnXCount){
        setTimeout(makeRandomXPosition, 3000); 
    }
    randomX = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)+1;
    console.log(randomX);
}


makeRandomXPosition();
```

If you want to do something with that `randomX`, you'll either need something else on a timer, or probably better, have that something call `makeRandomXPosition()` and then do its something afterwards.

```js
var randomX = 0;
var i = 0, spawnXCount = 10;

function makeRandomXPosition(){
    i++;  
    randomX = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)+1;
}

function doSomething() {
  makeRandomXPosition();
  console.log(randomX); // do something with randomX
  
  if (i < spawnXCount) {
    setTimeout(doSomething, 3000);
  }
}


doSomething();
```

In games, you'll typically have a main game loop which is responsible for triggering all the time based things and making overall decisions.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I realised that now. Any idea how I could fix that last part you mentioned?

Comment: The `doSomething()` I mentioned could be renamed `loop()` and it'd be your main game loop. Then you would just do certain things based on conditions, listing each function one after another. Take the `setTimeout()` out of the `if()` and make it always run. That time would then give you your FPS (frames per second) (so if you wanted to run at 60 FPS, you could give it 1000 / 60.

Comment: You could check out these examples I made about a year ago for some really simple games I made to teach a class: https://github.com/samanime/learning-games

Comment: Yeah, i have a main function called draw() with an requestAnimationFrame()